# Trouble installing MemCached Ubuntu 14.04 PHP 5.6

Tags: php, ubuntu, memcached

I've followed various guides for this, but just cannot get moving.

I've checked I've got PEAR installed.

`sudo apt-get install memcached php5-memcached`

then

`php -m | grep memcached`

a2enmod has no modules that look like memcached. So. Really just stuck at this point. All the guides say it should magically appear, and it simple doesn't.

Comment: Does netstat shows the memcached process?

Comment: Did you install MEMCACHED itself as well as the PHP extension that allows PHP to connect to MEMCACHED

Comment: netstat does not show anything related to memcached, @Axidepuy

Comment: I did install Memcached, and it is running. @RiggsFolly

Comment: @Axidepuy - It is listening in netstat. Sorry. Port 11211 at localhost is listening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right after the install I would check the state of the memcached with netstat:

```
netstat -pnatul | grep "memcached"
```

if the port and the pid are matches then:
`telnet 127.0.0.1 11211` and when the prompt appears: `stats` and `quit`

if it works, then into the shell (it will be just the CLI):

```
php -r '(new Memcached())->addServer("127.0.0.1", 11211) == true ? print "OK\n" : print "NF\n";'
```

But as you described above, the `php -m` shows no memcached at all, with dpkg check if the installation was properly finished.
The `dpkg -l | grep "php5"` lists every php5 related packages.

If its there, I would look for the extension line:

```
find /etc/ -type f -exec grep -lF "extension=memcached.so" {} \;
```

It will shows all the file's names with path that contains the `extension=memcached.so` if it returns with nothing insert that line into your php.ini file or to a separate config file called like `memcached.ini` and make sure it loads. Reload the apache.

Comment: Perfect. This found me the location and allowed me to find my mistake.

I have both php5 and php5.6 installed, I have one legacy app that requires 5 running. Thus what I needed to do was

`sudo apt-get php5.6-memcached`

previously I had installed the php5 version.

Thank you for the excellent instructions.

Answer (score 0):

```
service memcached restart
service apache2 restart
```

(and don't forget to configure your memcached to listen on the correct host/port)

Comment: Restarted both, nothing has changed. It is listening on the default 11211 port.